# Words for deep thought, concern... (Sentence example inside)

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing about a character who is currently pacing around his home in deep thought and concern. There is trouble approaching him shortly, and he is trying to find a solution. He is not afraid or nervous per-say - but he is in deep thought and concentration.

A sudden block of sorts has me searching for the right word for this situation.

Here are some examples:

"Within the dining room of the palace the King was _____ly pacing the floor"
"Knowing the police were on their way, James was ______ly considering his options"

Looking forward to reading your ideas!

Comment: You can use ***in contemplation***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**pensively**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pensive)

1. Engaged in deep and serious thought.